# Question about Zariski cancelation problem

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials

If $\mathbb{Q}[t_1,\ldots, t_n] = A[x_1,\ldots, x_{n-1}]$ has it been proven that $A\cong\mathbb{Q}[t]$?

Comment: This is an easy exercise.

Comment: I can only prove in case of algebraically closed field. Any hints to not closed field case?

Comment: @ulrich : what easy argument do you have in mind?

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is obviously a curve which is unirational over $\mathbb{Q}$. It is also clear that the space of complex points of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is contractible (in the analytic topology). There is only one curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has these two properties.

Comment: Is this argument valid for any other field which isn't algebraically closed but with zero characteristic?